# C++ 64 Bit compiler, what does it output?

Tags: 64-bit

I have suddenly had a bout of confusion around Mingw-64 compilers and other compilers which are said to be 64-bit.  Does this mean that the compiler is built to run on a 64 bit platform and compiles in 32-bit (this seems to be the case for all the Mingw-64 compilers I have found)?  Or does it mean that it will actually copile and build 64 bit binaries.

I want to build 64 bit binaries on a 64-bit compiler and am a little confused as to whether I am actually getting 64-bit outputs despite installing a 64-bit compiler?

There are a number of versions of Ming-64 bit around, eg: tdm, ming-64.. their binary directory seems to contain wing-32 binary files?

Answer (score 0):

A "64 bit compiler" will output 64 bit executables. It may or may not be 64 bit itself; MSVC++ for instance has a 64 bit compiler that's 32 bits itself.

Comment: Thanks, but was that designed to confuse me?  My only concern is that if I have a 64 bit compiler, can I take the program I compiled from it (the binary file) and run it on ta 64 bit system?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? It seems you don't understand what a 64 bit executable is, or what a 64 bit OS is.

Comment: That was the point of the question.  I think you're right.  I don't understand what  64-bit executable is!   If it's a 32-bit executable will it run on a 64 bit machine?